# Construction of OpenZeppelin voting contract with ٍERC777 token

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts, dao, voting

I managed to easily create governor and implement voting with erc20 token, but now I have erc777 token that I need to do this with, please guide me how I can I have to do this because when I introduce erc777 to governer contract during deployment, I get an error when creating the proposal.

Comment: What's the error?